# Set / modify the IdentityServer4's AccessTokenLifeTime value at run-time?

Tags: asp.net, identityserver4

Is it possible to modify / set the AccessTokenLifeTime value at run-time based on the claims' expiration date contained within the token?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to add your own custom expiry claim inside the access token, and then when you receive and authorize the token, then you can reject the access token if it has expired.

Think it can be a good idea to keep the access/refresh token lifetime to be static, and then handle custom expiration separately.

You could try to evaluate if the Client **UserSsoLifetime** property would help you?

see https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/reference/models/client/#authentication--session-management
and the sample test [here](https://github.com/DuendeSoftware/IdentityServer/blob/4ecb4e59fb95e4ceb9e9db0681b5933e89ba2450/test/IdentityServer.UnitTests/ResponseHandling/AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator/AuthorizeInteractionResponseGeneratorTests_Login.cs#L161)

The second alternative is to implement your own ITokenService, see the default implementation [here](https://github.com/DuendeSoftware/IdentityServer/blob/main/src/IdentityServer/Services/Default/DefaultTokenService.cs).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this may not be a solution that would work for my needs right now as we don't have control on the client to make a change to the token validity logic. Is IdentityServer4 really limited in abilities to be not able to set the token life time dynamically for each token?

Comment: see my updated answer